# AngularJS nested components and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a component for displaying a customer's address (please excuse the [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)):

```jade
address(style='{{addressStyle}}')
    strong {{clinic.businessName}}
    br
    span {{clinic.address.address1}}
    br
    span(ng-switch='{{clinic.address.address2 != null}}')
        span(ng-switch-when='true')
            | {{clinic.address.address2}}
            br
    span {{clinic.address.suburb}} {{clinic.address.state}} {{clinic.address.postcode}}
    br
    abbr(title='Phone') P:
    |  {{functions.formatPhoneNo(clinic.phone)}}
```

```js
app.directive('clinicAddress', function($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/clinicAddress',
        scope: { clinic: '=', functions: '=' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.addressStyle = attrs.style ? scope.addressStyle = $interpolate(attrs.style)() : '';
        }
    };
});
```

And another one, based on it, for displaying a customer's address wrapped in a hyperlink and with a map marker:

```jade
a(href='#!/clinic/{{clinic.urlFragment}}')
    div(style='width:50px;height:50px;background:url(/img/map/{{index+1}}.png) 190px 30px no-repeat;')
    clinic-address(clinic='clinic', functions='functions', style='background:url(/img/map/{{index+1}}.png) 190px 30px no-repeat;')
```

```js
app.directive('indexedClinicAddress', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { clinic: '=', index: '=', functions: '=' },
        templateUrl: 'directives/indexedClinicAddress'
    };
});
```

The problem is, when `$interpolate` runs in `clinicAddress`'s directive, `index` is undefined because it's in `indexedClinicAddress`'s scope. How can I make `$interpolate` use the parent scope, which I assume is the same scope as `indexedClinicAddress`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using $scope.$parent and $interpolate you should should use the scope `@` attribute - from [the Angular directives guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }, then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the parent scope (not component scope).

```js
app.directive('clinicAddress', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directives/clinicAddress',
    scope: { clinic: '=', functions: '=', addressStyle:'@style' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Interestingly, I'm still getting a 404 when the browser tries to get the uninterpolated resource in the style. I think that was throwing me all along. Now that I'm still seeing it, I think it's just the browser doing it's thing because the attribute is called `style`.

Comment: Theory confirmed. Now using `elementStyle` instead of `style` to prevent an unnecessary request to the server which will otherwise respond with `404`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$scope.$parent
```

to get a reference to the parent scope